# Where is the scanning and parsing front end source code in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

does anybody know where is the scanning and parsing source code implemented in Racket? (not the lexer/parser generator implementation in Racket.) I explored the Racket source code for a little bit, but seriously confused, and still expecting to see how (scanning/parsing/compiling and interpreting pipe lined up....).

Answer (score 3):

Start here: http://git.racket-lang.org/plt/blob/HEAD:/src/racket/src/read.c